# C++ std::cin Unhandled exception: Access violation writing location 

Tags: c++, std, access-violation, cin

I'm getting an access violation when trying to use `std::cin`. I'm using a `char*` and it's not allowing me to input my data.

```
void Input(){
while(true){
    char* _input = "";
    std::cin >> _input; //Error appears when this is reached..
    std::cout << _input;
    //Send(_input);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation Fault With Char Array and Pointer in C on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773079/segmentation-fault-with-char-array-and-pointer-in-c-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a buffer for `cin` to store the data into.

`operator>>(std::istream&, std::string)` will allocate storage for the string being read, but you're using `operator>>(std::istream&, char*)` which writes to a caller-provided buffer, and you didn't provide a writable buffer (string literals are not writable), so you got an access violation.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* _input = ""; // note: it's deprecated; should have been "const char*"
```

`_input` is pointer pointing to a string literal. Inputting into it is an undefined behavior.
Either use

```
char _input[SIZE]; // SIZE declared by you to hold the enough characters
```

or

```
std::string _input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char _input[1024];
std::cin >> _input;
std::cout << _input;
```

Or better:

```
std::string _input;
std::cin >> _input;
std::cout << _input;
```