# assigning a char - segmentation fault

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    char *str[]={"aa","bb"};
    str[0][0]='h';
}
```

I receive a segmentation fault when executing this code. Does anyone know the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Segmentation Fault With Char Array and Pointer in C on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773079/segmentation-fault-with-char-array-and-pointer-in-c-on-linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning to a location occupied by a string constant, an undefined behavior. If you know the max lengths of your strings, you can do this:

```
char ss[][3] = {"aa", "bb"};
```

It's not a precise equivalent, but it should work. If you do not know max length, or do not want to waste a few bytes here and there, you can still pull it off with a little more work:

```
char aa[] = "aa";
char bbbb[] = "bbbb";
char *ss[] = {aa, bbbb};
```

Answer (score 3):

You are attempting to update a literal constant, which is not allowed.  It would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: It is not *required* to work by ISO C, and not *allowed* by this compiler/environment (at least by default: there may be a way to request it to work). GCC used to allow this with `-fwritable-strings` support for which has been removed.